# documentation page for qt connect()

Tags: c

I am unable to find the QT documentation page which specifies errors for the connect function found in `<sys/socket.h>`

Reason:

```
int err = connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
```

returns -1,

socket.h file:

```
/* Open a connection on socket FD to peer at ADDR (which LEN bytes long).
   For connectionless socket types, just set the default address to send to
   and the only address from which to accept transmissions.
   Return 0 on success, -1 for errors.

   This function is a cancellation point and therefore not marked with
   __THROW.  */
extern int connect (int __fd, __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG __addr, socklen_t __len);
```

Which doc page gives information about why this connect fails?

Comment: Is it a QT  file `<sys/socket.h>` ?

Comment: @BenceKaulics yes, but searching for the file in the doc page does not yield anything

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/connect.html

Comment: Because it is no QT function.

Comment: @Olaf that is a very helpful comment, you certainly answered my question!

Comment: @KGCybeX: You should keep that in mind next time you don't find documentation in one library. It might be in another one. Hint: Searching the Linux man-pages for unknown function is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect()` in `<sys/socket.h>` is not part of `qt` but of POSIX, you can take a look to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/connect)

And to get information about why `connect()` fails you can use [perror()](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/perrorman.html):

> Since so many functions return -1 on error and set the value of the
>   variable errno to be some number, it would sure be nice if you could
>   easily print that in a form that made sense to you.
>
> Mercifully, perror() does that. If you want more description to be
>   printed before the error, you can point the parameter s to it (or you
>   can leave s as NULL and nothing additional will be printed.)
>
> In a nutshell, this function takes errno values, like ECONNRESET, and
>   prints them nicely, like "Connection reset by peer."
>
> The function strerror() is very similar to perror(), except it returns
>   a pointer to the error message string for a given value (you usually
>   pass in the variable errno.)

```
if ((err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    perror("connect");
```